# Defining an enum in C++ class definition: ‘MyEnum’ has not been declared

Tags: c++, class, oop

I'm attempting to both define and use an `enum` in a C++ class definition, but I get the following error:

```sh
error: ‘myEnum’ has not been declared
```

### `MyClass.h`

```cpp
#ifndef MyClass_H
#define MyClass_H

class MyClass
{
public:
   
   MyClass();
   ~MyClass();

   enum myEnum
   {
      A = 0,
      B = 1,
      C = 2
   };

   int myArray[myEnum::C];
};

#endif
```

### `Class2.h`

```cpp
#ifndef Class2_H
#define Class2_H

#include "MyClass.h" // I only get the error when I try to include MyClass here.

class Class2
{

// stuff

};

#endif
```

What am I doing wrong here? NOTE: I only get this error when I try to `#include MyClass.h` into the `Class2.h` file.

Comment: you need to use `enum class` instead of `enum` to use `myEnum::C`

Comment: @Frank I don't think that's true (https://godbolt.org/z/17qx6G)

Comment: Can you post the full error? Are you sure it is pointing to the line in `MyClass.h`? Because I cannot get it to fail.

Comment: Also, which compiler are you using?

Comment: I just want to point out that for a [mcve] you shouldn't need `OtherClass` or its header file. Just a simple simple array of `int` should be enough to trigger the error.

Comment: @dreamlax Sorry, I added the line where it triggers a fail. It's when I try to include "MyClass.h" in another file.

Comment: @dreamlax gcc version 4.8.5

Comment: Show the compiler switches you are using as well

Comment: You could do `int myArray[C];` as a workaround if it turns out this version doesn't support

Comment: GCC version 4.8 is *ancient* and doesn't even support all of the C++11 standard. I highly recommend you upgrade. GCC is up to version 10.2 now. You need at least version 6 to have C++11 enabled by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a C++98 compiler, you cannot use the `enum::x` syntax. The `::` scope resolution operator is only defined for namespaces and classes in C++98. Enumerations were added in C++11. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers)

> A qualified id-expression is an unqualified id-expression prepended by a scope resolution operator ::, and optionally, a sequence of <kbd>enumeration, (since C++11)</kbd> class or namespace names

Comment: I'm using C++0x

Comment: Unfortunately, C++0x is not new enough (and it is not actually a standard),. If you want to use enumerations like this, you have to use C++11, which I think came in around GCC 5.